# Multiple IP address variable in Azure ARM Template

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager

If I am using an ARM Template to create an IP Group within Azure and want to add Multiple IP Addresses as a Parameter rather than putting them in the body of the resource is this possible?

The template is as follows

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/ipGroups",
  "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {
    "tagName1": "tagValue1",
    "tagName2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "properties": {
    "ipAddresses": [ "10.10.10.10",
      "10.10.10.11" ]
  }
}
```

If I create a Parameter like the following

```
        "ipgipaddress": {
            "type": "string
            "Value": 
                "10.10.10.10",
                "10.10.10.11"
        }
```

And update the code to

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/ipGroups",
  "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {
    "tagName1": "tagValue1",
    "tagName2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "properties": {
    "ipAddresses": "[parameters('ipgroupsettings')]"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want to add Multiple IP Addresses as a Parameter rather than putting
> them in the body of the resource is this possible?

Yes it is possible, you can add Multiple IP Addresses as a Parameter. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/ipgroups?tabs=json), the property `ipAddresses` is of type string array.

To reproduce this ,In our ARM Template we have initialized those `ipaddresses` to a parameter of type array & further passed those values using `"[paramerter(ipaddresses)]"`.

We have tested this, it is working fine.

**Here is the ARM Template** :

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "ipaddress":{
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": ["10.0.1.0/27","10.0.2.0/27"]
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [{
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/ipGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "testipgroups",
        "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties":{
            "ipAddresses": "[parameters('ipaddress')]"
        }
    }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "ipaddress":{
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "10.0.1.0/27,10.0.2.0/27"
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {
      "iparray": "[split(parameters('ipaddress'),',')]"

     },
    "resources": [{
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/ipGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "testipgroups",
        "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties":{
            "ipAddresses": "[variables('iparray')]"
        }
    }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
   }
```

> If you want to save your time in providing input as String without much double quotes(" ") ,use split function with removing delimiter (comma in above example) which will create an array of IP's.